# How to restart certain Linux services

Tags: centos, services

What are the commands to restart the following services on CentOS?

- `cpdavd`
- `cpsrvd`
- `leechprot`
- `spamd`
- `tailwatch`

Comment: Which version of CentOS?

Answer (score 1):

If you have CentOS 7

```
systemctl restart cpdavd cpsrvd leechprot spamd tailwatch
```

If you have CentOS 6

```
service cpdavd restart
service cpsrvd restart
service leechprot restart
service spamd restart
service tailwatch restart
```